# Calculate the amounts in table (td)

Tags: angularjs, sql-server, web-services, html-table

I am creating a web app in which I am fetching the data (expense of the employee).

I want to calculate the amount of all the td and print the amount.

I am  using angularjs for fetching the data.

Here is my table:

```
<tr>
                <th colspan="2" style="border:1px solid black">Payment Id</th>
                <th colspan="2" style="border:1px solid black">Date Of Issue</th>
                <th colspan="2" style="border:1px solid black">Date Of Trainer</th>
                <th colspan="1" style="border:1px solid black">Training Id</th>
                <th colspan="2" style="border:1px solid black">Payment Mode</th>
                <th colspan="2" style="border:1px solid black">Cheque/ UTR no</th>
                <th style="border:1px solid black">Amount</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="i in getexpenseinfo">
                <td colspan="2" style="border:1px solid black">{{i.paymentid}}</td>
                <td colspan="2" style="border:1px solid black">{{i.dateofissue}}</td>
                <td colspan="2" style="border:1px solid black">{{i.dateoftransfer}}</td>
                <td colspan="1" style="border:1px solid black">{{i.trainingid}}</td>
                <td colspan="2" style="border:1px solid black">{{i.paymentmode}}</td>
                <td colspan="2" style="border:1px solid black">{{i.chequeno}}</td>
                <td style="border:1px solid black">{{i.amount}}</td>
            </tr>
```

the column `{{i.amount}}` is fetching the amount spent on expenses here is my controller for the same

```
$http.get('/paymentrpt.asmx/expenseinforpt', {
                params: {
                    datefrm: $scope.datefrm,
                    dateto: $scope.dateto,
                    empname: $scope.emp
                }
            }).then(function (response) {

                $scope.getexpenseinfo = response.data.info;
                $scope.pageload = false;
            });
```

and my webservice where I am fetching the data:

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
        public void expenseinforpt(string datefrm, string dateto, string empname)
        {
            List<object> expenseinfo = new List<object>();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("prolltexpense", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            SqlParameter[] param = {
                new SqlParameter("@from",datefrm),
                new SqlParameter("@to",dateto),
                new SqlParameter("@trainer",empname)
            };
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                expenseinfo.Add(new
                {
                    trainingno = dr["trainingno"].ToString(),
                    expenseno=dr["expenseno"].ToString(),
                    expensehead=dr["expensehead"].ToString(),
                    amount=dr["amt"].ToString(),
                    remark=dr["remark"].ToString(),
                    claim=dr["gigeraccount1"].ToString()
                });
            }
            var json = js.Serialize(expenseinfo);
            Context.Response.Write("{" + '"' + "info" + '"' + ":" + json + "}");
            con.Close();
        }
```

and this is my stored procedure from where I am getting the amount:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prolltexpense (@from varchar(50),@to varchar(50),@trainer varchar(50))  

AS  
BEGIN  
select expense.trainingno,expense.expenseno,expense.expensehead,expense.amt,expense.remark,(case when expense.gigeraccount=1 then 'YES' when expense.gigeraccount=0 then 'NO' end) as gigeraccount1 from instructoreexpense left outer join sonvininsert on son
vininsert.sonvinid=instructoreexpense.sonvinid left outer join finalinstructoreexpense on finalinstructoreexpense.sonvinid=instructoreexpense.sonvinid join expense on sonvininsert.trainingno=expense.trainingno  where sonvininsert.date between convert(date
time,@from,105) and convert(datetime,@to,105) and sonvininsert.trainer=@trainer  order by sonvininsert.date  

END
```

What do I need to do if I want to calculate the amount of the table?

This is how my table looks:

```
Training Id Expense No. Expense Head    Amount  Remark  Claim
16100800002 16100800002001  Conveyance  20  Kurla to Mumbra Return by train NO
16100800002 16100800002002  Conveyance  80  Mumbra stn. to School by auto Patrick, Kishan & me  NO
16100800002 16100800002003  Conveyance  45  School to Mumbra stn. by auto Patrick, Kisan & me   NO
16111800006 16111800006001  F&B 110 Dinner in train on 17th NO
16111800006 16111800006002  Conveyance  18  Residence to Vile parle stn. by auto on 17th    NO
16111800006 16111800006003  Travelling  150 Hotel to Guru Nanak school by auto  NO
16111800006 16111800006004  Travelling  30  Guru nanak school to hotel by sharing auto and bus  NO
16111800006 16111800006006  Conveyance  18  Vile parle to residence by auto on 19th NO
16111800006 16111800006005  F&B 287 Breakfast, Lunch & dinner   NO



(B) Payable
0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know about angularjs but u can do it easily from sql-server

```
select sum (expense.amt) as totalamt
 from instructoreexpense left outer join sonvininsert on 
sonvininsert.sonvinid=instructoreexpense.sonvinid left outer join finalinstructoreexpense on 
finalinstructoreexpense.sonvinid=instructoreexpense.sonvinid join expense 
on sonvininsert.trainingno=expense.trainingno   where sonvininsert.date 
between convert(datetime,@from,105) 
and convert(datetime,@to,105) and sonvininsert.trainer=@trainer
```

let me know if it gives you error because i use your given code and i don't know expense is int or varchar in your sql